# How to run psycopg2.extras.execute_values() without committing?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am running:

```
def db_connect():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host=host,
        database=database, 
        user=user,
        password=password
    )
    return conn


data_to_insert = []
for a, b, c in data_source:  # len(data_source) > 100000
   data_to_insert.append(a, b, c) 


def insert_to_table():

    request = "INSERT INTO tablename " \ 
              "(a, b, c) " \
              "VALUES " \
              "%s "

    do_commit = False

    with db_connect() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
                psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, request, data_to_insert, template=None)

        if do_commit:
            conn.commit() # this line could be completely omitted
```

And still It commits. Is it possible to avoid that? If I remember correctly, other, slower ways to do things, like `cur.execute()`, did'n have that problem.

`psycopg2.__version__` is `2.8.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)`

PostgreSQL 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, conn will commit after it gets out of '[with](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement)' statement.

> Starting from version 2.5, psycopg2’s connections and cursors are
>   context managers and can be used with the with statement:
>
> ```
> with psycopg2.connect(DSN) as conn:
>     with conn.cursor() as curs:
>         curs.execute(SQL)
> ```
>
> When a connection exits the with block, if no exception has been raised by the block, the transaction is
>   committed. In case of exception the transaction is rolled back.

So instead of doing:

```
if do_commit:
    conn.commit()
```

do

```
if not do_commit:
    conn.rollback()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But I thought, `conn` was still in  the scope of first `with`, then maybe I'm missing something basic?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Yes, it's in the scope of first with. Could you elaborate more on your question?

Comment: Sure, I added `db_connect()`, `request` and `data` definitions, to the question. What else could be related to the issue?

Comment: From what I understand you are returning from db_connect() function 'conn'. 'with' statement will open transaction and if there are no errors it will automatically commit transaction at the exit of 'with'. So in your code you don't have to commit, since it's already done by 'with' statement. But you need to rollback or raise an exception if you would like your data not to be committed. Please read more about it at the link that I provided in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I got it,  Conn commits on exit, after `if` clause, regardless, and if we do `rollback` there is nothing to commit